# Is this function infinitely differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let 
>   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(1-\frac{1}{1-|x|}\right),\,\,&|x|<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
>   and show that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

I took the derivative and obtained 
$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{\text{sgn}(x)}{(1-|x|)^2}\exp\left(1-\frac{1}{1-|x|}\right),\,\,&|x|<1\\0,&\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
which does not look to be continous at $x=0$ and thus is not continuously differentiable. Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've written here, I can't see anything wrong, except a misssing negative sign in front of everything. The only thing I can think of is that you might have copied it wrong. If not, then the problem itself is wrong (presumably there is a typo somewhere).